# Fourier Series-Distribution

Tags: fourier-series, distribution-theory

Good day, I am trying to solve an exercise in the course of distribution theory and fourier analysis. I am new to the matter of using distribution in calculating, and I am thankful for any help to solve the following question:

1. Consider the $2\pi$ -periodic function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,2\pi)$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\pi-x)$.
   prove (by calculating the Fourier series) that in the sense of distributions
   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}=f(x)$.
2. prove that-in the sense of distributions

   $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{inx}=2\pi\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\delta_{2\pi n}$ in $D^{'}(\mathbb{R})$
   Where $\delta_{2\pi n}$ is the distribution $\phi  \mapsto \phi (2 \pi n)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question I have tried the following:
if one takes the distribution < sum e^{inx} , phi > = .... 
Then by taking the sum like this (-infinity,-1) & {0} & (1,infinity)
With the notation of cos(nx) as a function of e^{inx}
With the help of the derivative of f(x)
the previous distribution may equal to <0,phi(x)>

Then I didn't know how to continue to get the second hand side (2 pi sum delta 2 pi n)
Sorry